# Fitting Gaussian Mixture Model

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have six bivariate normal distributions and I want to combine them as a Gaussian mixture model. I calculated the mean and covariance matrices below. When I sample random data (mvnrnd) for given distribution parameters, gmdistribution.fit  gives different results for different sample sizes. In other words, random sampling sizes n=50 and n=1000 converge different  gaussian distributions. My underlying data contains 30 samples for each cluster. So what is the best way to fit gaussian mixture model to my data? Any ideas?

```
mu1=[log(0.29090) log(0.0038)]
mu2=[log(0.4017) log(0.0053)]
mu3=[log(0.4477) log(0.0051)]
mu4=[log(0.5396) log(0.0072)]
mu5=[log(0.6881) log(0.0090)]
mu6=[log(0.8091) log(0.0099)]

cov1=[0.052 0.0011;0.0011 0.044]
cov2=[0.054 0.0010;0.0010 0.078]
cov3=[0.126 0.011;0.011 0.23]
cov4=[0.092 0.0061;0.0061 0.12]
cov5=[0.113 0.0092;0.0092 0.14]
cov6=[0.1047 0.0217;0.0217 0.35]


X = [mvnrnd(mu1,cov1,50);mvnrnd(mu2,cov2,50);mvnrnd(mu3,cov3,50);mvnrnd(mu4,cov4,50);mvnrnd(mu5,cov5,50);mvnrnd(mu6,cov6,50)];
scatter(X(:,1),X(:,2),'g')

options = statset('MaxIter',200,'Display','final','TolFun',1e-6)


obj = gmdistribution.fit(X,6,'Options',options)

hold on
ezcontour(@(x,y)pdf(obj,[x y]),[-2.5 1],[-7 -2.5],300);
hold off
ezsurfc(@(x,y) pdf(obj,[x y]))

x = -2.5:0.1:1.5; y = -7.0:0.1:-3; n=length(x); a=zeros(n,n);
for i = 1:n,
for j = 1:n,
    gaussPDF(i,j) = pdf(obj,[x(i) y(j)]);

end;
end;
```

Comment: There are many algorithms one can use to estimate Gaussian mixtures: EM methods, k-harmonic means...

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Michael J. I think the Matlab already implements the EM algorithm to estimate parameters. I want to clarify my question. For example my observation data (with sample size 30) gives mean and covariance matrices, but if I form the multivariate random distribution with larger sample sizes. Does it affect the fitting results?

Comment: Yes. Different sample size affects the final result of your model. For example if you simulate a data with 300 and 3000 observations, then you will get different results (maybe no much different).